# Do I need to study Subprocesses to make this python source code work within another programming language?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, subprocess

This part of the embedded python source code works.

```
//Native Source Code [C - Like Language]
string zncauth = nick + ":" + password;

//Initializes Python for executing [Python Source Code]
PyInit();

//Python Source Code
PyExecute("import socket");

// Create Connetion
PyExecute("server_addr = '127.0.0.1'");
PyExecute("server_port = 6667");
PyExecute("s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)");
PyExecute("s.connect((server_addr, server_port))");   
PyExecute("s.send( \'NICK botnick\\r\\n\')");   
PyExecute("s.send( \'USER znc bot znc :znc\\r\\n\')");  
PyExecute("s.send( \'PASS " + zncauth + " \\r\\n\')");
```

This is the problem. It times out after 9 minutes and is disconnected from the server. My guess is the `while statement` runs once.

```
// Ping Pong    
PyExecute("while True:\'\\n\'");    
PyExecute("data = s.recv(4096)");
PyExecute("if data.find( \"PING\" ) != -1:\'\\n\'");
PyExecute("s.send ( \'PONG \' + data.split() [ 1 ] + \'\\r\\n\' )");
PyExecute("if data.find ( \'You need to send your password. Try /quote PASS <username>:<password>\' ) != -1:\'\\n\'");
PyExecute("s.send (\'PASS " + zncauth + " \\r\\n\')");
```

This is the latest version of the problem while loop I've tried. When it runs, there is no noticeable difference in this or the above version of the while loop.

```
    PyExecute("data = s.recv(4096)");
PyExecute("while data != 0:\'\\n\'");   
PyExecute("if data.find( \"PING\" ) != -1:\'\\n\'");
PyExecute("if data == 0:\'\\n\'");
PyExecute("break");
```

This is the executable of the same python code above. It stays on the irc network for hours, but I need to send messages through the connection it's created. I need to either find a way to send messages through this executable which will in turn process the message or embed the `while statement` properly so that it works in the native code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

//Test.py
import socket

zncauth = 'nick:password'
server_addr = '127.0.0.1'
server_port = 6667
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server_addr, server_port))   
s.send( 'NICK botnick\r\n')
s.send( 'USER znc bot znc :znc\r\n')
s.send( 'PASS ' + zncauth + ' \r\n')

while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
        s.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )
    if data.find ( 'You need to send your password. Try /quote PASS <username>:<password>' ) != -1:
        s.send ('PASS ' + zncauth + ' \r\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it's not clear what `PyExecute` actually is; it isn't provided by Python itself. I've found one library out there that provides things called `PyInit` and `PyExecute` -- it offers Python integration for something called Metatrader -- and I'm going to guess that that's what you're using. Even if you're not, what you're actually using may be similar enough for what follows still to make sense.

So, anyway, what you're doing now certainly can't be right: what do you expect the Python interpreter to do when you tell it to execute `while True:`? The only possible answers are (1) an infinite loop with an empty loop body, and (2) nothing until you've somehow provided the loop body *and told it you've finished doing so*. The first of those subdivides into (1a) do nothing useful because it's a syntax error and (1b) loop for ever doing nothing. None of these outcomes is going to be any use to you. (I am pretty sure the actual answer is either (1a) or (1b) but haven't checked which.)

What you actually need to do is to provide `PyExecute` -- which I think is a thin wrapper around the actually-part-of-Python `PyRun_SimpleString` -- with a complete statement to execute. That would be the whole loop. So give it the whole thing, including newlines *and indentation*, and see if that behaves better.

I emphasized "and indentation" there because as it stands your code is wrongly indented, and in Python indentation is actually used by the parser. The relevant bit probably wants to be something like this:

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
        s.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )
    if data.find ( 'You need to send your password. Try /quote PASS <username>:<password>' ) != -1:
        s.send ('PASS ' + zncauth + ' \r\n')
```

The stuff before the loop, being just one statement per line, is probably fine as it is.

To clarify what I meant by "give it the whole thing": you need a *single* string containing the multi-line code, something like this:

```
PyExecute(
    "while True:\n"
    "  data = s.recv(4096)\n"
    "  if (data.find('PING') != -1:\n"
    "    s.send('PONG' + data.split()[1] + '\\r\\n')\n"
    ...)
```

where

- each line ends with an explicit `\n`
- each line is appropriately indented with spaces at the start
- I've used C's automatic-concatenation feature where if you write a bunch of `"..."` strings with only whitespace between them they get treated as a single longer string; if you're actually writing in some other C-like language and it happens not to support that syntax then the code will look a bit uglier
- backslashes inside the code are escaped (again I'm assuming C syntax for strings, which may or may not be correct if you're using a different language)

Comment: I removed the indentation from the executable for readability on stackoverflow. But I'll keep it next time. Yes, `PyExecute` is part of an integration package for Metatrader [MQL4], which is the the native code in question. I will work on finishing the loop and see if that fixes it. Thank you.

Comment: I might be able to find some support using `PyRun_SimpleString`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? What exactly did you try and what happened when you tried?

Comment: It takes 9 minutes to find out if each version works. :) Most notably, I tried the examples here: [http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) Both versions connected to the server and disconnected in 9 minutes. The only one that hasn't disconnected and is still running is the example executable above.

Comment: I don't understand. The examples there are completely different code. Do you mean you tried exactly the examples there, or you tried some variant on the code above based on those, or what? Can't you post the exact code you tried that timed out? (When you say "the example executable above", do you mean the pure-Python one, or something else?)

Comment: I posted my latest code above. The example executable is now labeled **test.py**

Comment: Ah, I see: I'm afraid you're confused about what I meant; I'm about to edit what I wrote to make it clearer. My apologies.

Comment: OK, edited. Take a look at the end of my answer; does that make any more sense now?

Comment: Interesting. Well, I understand now. :) Thanks. I'll try this way, in a number of ways if this particular version doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I haven't gotten it to work the way I want it to but your suggestion allows the code to run. There are immediately noticeable differences. I'm not completely certain, but I'm fairly certain this is the answer I've been pummeling over for days. Thanks again.